# Get All Anchors In a Given URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor, href

I need to get all the anchors in a given URL.

I tried using

```
var elements = $('a[href="' + txtHref + '"]');
```

Where txtHref is the given URL by the user but it always returned empty.

I saw a lot of examples of getting all the "a" from the current web page but I need all the "a" in a given web page.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$('a[href="' + txtHref + '"]')` should work. Can you share the URL and HTML content?

Comment: An example of a URL is "http://jobs.thejobnetwork.com". I should get 9 results but got nothing

Comment: Please make a js fiddle so we can test out your code

Comment: This is my JS code: var txtHref = $("#txtURL").val(); var elements = $('a[href="' + txtHref + '"]');